# Alfresco AVMSyncException error

Tags: java, content-management-system, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I deleted a project in alfresco and after that I created it with the same name but something is not working well. I get an error when I try to submit files:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{DialogManager.bean.workflowListSize != 0}'
caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{DialogManager.bean.workflowListSize != 0}'
caused by:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{DialogManager.bean.workflowListSize != 0}'
caused by:
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Cannot get value for expression '#{DialogManager.bean.workflowListSize != 0}'
caused by:
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception getting value of property workflowListSize of base of type : com.xxxxxxx.alfresco.web.bean.wcm.ValidatingSubmitDialog
caused by:
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Bean: com.xxxxxxx.alfresco.web.bean.wcm.ValidatingSubmitDialog, property: workflowListSize
caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
caused by:
org.alfresco.service.cmr.avmsync.AVMSyncException: 012114151 Source not found: my-project--workflow-a6aeb8d6-0cae-4eb7-a1ed-a86498e6beb7:/www
```

Comment: I know this doesn't help you but the AVM functionality was deprecated many years ago and removed from the product. It may be hard finding people who still use it or know how it works. You should be looking at alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff. Unfortunately you are right, I do use a very old version of Alfresco and I am constrained to use it further.

Comment: Is that com.xxxxxxx.alfresco.web.bean.wcm.ValidatingSubmitDialog class something custom?